# Is it possible to use multiple post_name, post_title and post_content?

Tags: plugins, permalinks, rewrite-rules, localization

I'm actually writing a localization plugin. Here I have developed something like "`localhost/post-title`", "`localhost/de/post-title`", "`localhost/ru/post-title`".

From this point on, is it possible to join me with a query like "`localhost/de/ beitragstitel`" and "`localhost/ru/Заголовок-поста`" and more... so that the two persistent links point to the same content, such as "post_name_de"?

Of course I have to do all this for "`post_title`" and "`post_content`".

So I need to change the content and the permanent link according to the incoming language prefixes. So is it possible?

Comment: out of the box? No. You would need custom rewrite rules, and you couldn't store those additional post slugs in the `post_name`/`post_title`/etc. Keep in mind that there are existing localisation plugins that support this via other means. If you have a question that asks "Is it possible" usually the answer is yes, the real question is how many years of modifications are necessary to produce the result, and is it really necessary to do that when other methods exist?

Comment: @TomJNowell a very nice answer. I erased the extra field idea from my head. Can you elaborate on the rewrite rules for multi slugs? So how do I make multiple "slug" rules for a "post"?

Comment: I've reviewed other localization plugins. Each translated language keeps its content in a single field with a specific separator, which means that for a language, it always attracts content from all languages.

Comment: Most people don't, they just use multiple posts, or, they have multisites with parallel blogs. As for how to map additional "slugs" that's a new question, and involves new data storage